# How to return a value from async function used inside .map function in React?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, firebase-storage

So I googled a bit and I found that async function return promise which result value can be accessed by using .then() after this async function. That is why it can't render properly. My question is: how can I render an actual value from this promise inside .map?

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("/assets")

const [productList, setProductList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/product/get").then((response) => {
        setProductList(response.data)
    })  
}, [])

const getImage = async (bannerImage) => {
    const url = await storageRef.child(bannerImage).getDownloadURL();
    return url;   
}
```

Map function (returns `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])`):

```
{productList.map((val) => {
    return (
        <div key={val.id} className="product">
            <div className="item">
                <h1>Product title: {val.title}</h1>
                <h2>Price: {val.price}</h2>
                <h2>Quantity: {val.quantity}</h2>
                <h2>IMG: {getImage(val.bannerImage)}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) 
})}
```

Comment: The same way you render productList. It's async as well. however... i'd suggest finding a better way to get the data than sending an ajax request in a loop. ideally return it as part of the product data, or request all the images at once.

Comment: The problem is your `getImage` function. It returns a Promise, and you're trying to render it. The solution is to do the same thing as with your `productList`, after loading it. Something like: `const images = await Promise.all(response.data.map(val => storageRef.child(val.bannerImage).getDownloadURL()));`

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to invoke `getImage` in the `.then` callback for the `Axios.get` call in `useEffect`?

Comment: Because I want to render each image for each product object from productList. Each product has bannerImage attribute and this attribute has to match the url. And sorry if this is a silly question. It is for a school project so I have to do it although I am new to react. And I have only 3 months to learn React and create  this ecommerce site project.

Comment: `Because I want to render each image for each product object from productList` that doesn't mean you cannot do what Jared is suggesting. You still have to do that. Again: the way to do this is to load the image URLs from the database right after loading the list of products and putting them into a state array. Now you can use that array to display the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @Chris-G suggested, you could map over `response.data` in the `.then` chained on `Axios.get` to go ahead, get the image URLs, and construct the objects that you'll need for the render. Example:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("/assets");
const getImage = async (bannerImage) => {
    const url = await storageRef.child(bannerImage).getDownloadURL();
    return url;   
}

const [productList, setProductList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/product/get").then((response) => {
        Promise.all(response.data.map(async (rawProduct) => {
            const renderReadyProduct = {
                title: rawProduct.title,
                price: rawProduct.price,
                quantity: rawProduct.quantity
            };
            renderReadyProduct.img = await getImage(rawProduct.bannerImage);
            return renderReadyProduct;
        })).then((newProductList) => setProductList(newProductList));
    });
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't access `val.bannerImage` because I am initializing val variable in return() after all this code. To be more specific: I have functional component then I have your code wrapped in it, then after your code I have return() and inside this return I have the above mentioned map which renders products in divs.

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my eight-hour puzzle :D